# Hot Restart not working anymore, can't debug app at all

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I had made some changes to both XAML and code-behind, and went to see the changes on my physical iPad. I saw that my changes weren't being reflected, so I deleted the app and expected it to reinstall. However, from that point, I received this error every time I tried to debug on the device:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error running hotrestart: 'An error occurred while signing the application 'TraceIt.iOS.app'. Details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. Command: 'sign -i="C:\Users\Gorilla Rig\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Bundles\16.7.000.440\a0005e492e54334d6dcf94dfaa23baba\TraceIt.iOS.app" -p="C:\Users\Gorilla Rig\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles\042184b7-110e-4dc3-abab-635382ed7659.mobileprovision" -c="C:\Users\Gorilla Rig\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates\2E160A7E60AF6F7B.p12" -pk="CFBundleIdentifier" -pv="com.companyname.TraceIt" -w="145b2541-08e5-43e5-b15a-b7a650b26f22"' TraceIt.iOS*

I tried on my iPhone, same issue. Deleted the app, making sure it wasn't in the middle of loading anything, but alas, the same problem. I have attempted going to iOS Bundle Signing settings and reloading the provisioning profile. Nothing.

Debugging works fine on Android.

What can I do?

Comment: delete bin and obj folders from ios and pcl projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's best to do a clean and rebuild the solution. On iOS, if you try to delete an application from the device, and then reinstall into a directory which does not exist (in this case the app you deleted), then it will fail.

If that doesn't work, then close visual studio, and reopen, along with repeating the above process.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the *AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin* folder and then downloading all profiles worked for me.

Comment: This should be the answer