# Error running hotrestart: 'An unexpected error occurred and the process has been terminated'

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

HotRestart has been working fine but it has been awhile since I tried it. I have upgraded Visual Studio 2019 to 16.7.3 latest version. Since it is running the signing command, I would think there is an issue with signing the iOS application and deploying to my iPad device which has worked fine in the past. How do I determine exactly what is failing and how to fix the issue?

```
Error running hotrestart: 'An unexpected error occurred and the process has been terminated'. 
    Command: 'sign 
    -i="C:\Users\orgbr\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Bundles\16.7.000.440\fcf6121cf34b44a6384edbf0e75e37ea\HealthManager.iOS.app" 
            -p="C:\Users\orgbr\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles\a522c89e-17b8-4139-82de-b73df3481e99.mobileprovision" 
            -c="C:\Users\orgbr\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates\3328C25D55251B30.p12" 
            -pk="CFBundleIdentifier" -pv="com.orgbrat.HealthManager" -w="43535a82-2b8a-4726-9445-41ca58f4e1ce"' 

    HealthManager.iOS   
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Local.targets  300
```

Comment: Can you please have a try with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63472945/10539446)? The problem is similar to you.

Comment: Tried the above solution with no success. I get this error even if I right click the iOS project in Visual Studio and just say Rebuild. Why would it run hotrestart on just a pure rebuild?

Comment: Since it is still in [preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#troubleshoot), you can report a problem by the feedback tool at Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.